# No matching function for call to 'merge(std::vector<int>&, std::vector<int>&)

Tags: c++, vector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

std::vector <int> mergesort(std::vector <int> list)
{
    int n = list.size();
    if(n == 1)
    {
        return list;    
    }
    std::vector<int> v2(list.begin(), list.begin() + list.size()/2),
               v3(list.begin() + list.size()/2, list.end()); 
    v2 = mergesort(v2);
    v3 = mergesort(v3);
    return merge(v2, v3);

}

std::vector <int> merge(std::vector <int> list1, std::vector <int> list2)
{
    std::vector <int> list3; 
    while(list1.size() > 0 && list2.size() > 0)
    {
        if(list1[0] > list2[0])
        {
            list3.push_back (list2[0]);
            list2.erase (list2.begin());
        }
        else
        {
            list3.push_back (list1[0]);
            list1.erase (list1.begin());
        }
    }
    while(list1.size() > 0)
    {
        list3.push_back (list1[0]);
        list1.erase (list1.begin());
    }
    while(list2.size() > 0)
    {
        list3.push_back (list2[0]);   
        list2.erase (list2.begin());     
    }
    return list3;
}
int main()
{

}
```

I am getting a error at line 16 and the error is:

```
No matching function for call to 'merge(std::vector<int>&, std::vector<int>&)
```

Am I doing something wrong with return `merge(v2,v3);` ?

Is it with something with pointers by judging the error?

I have tried declaring as a pointer vector to see if that would work but it does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++, like C, reads from top to bottom.  At the point in `mergesort` where it calls `merge`, that function doesn't exist.  Either invert implementations or declare `merge` above `mergesort`.

Answer (score 3):

You have to declare the merge function before referencing:

```
extern std::vector <int> merge(std::vector <int> list1, std::vector <int> list2);
return merge(v2, v3);
```

Answer (score 3):

In C++ you have to *declare* functions before calling them.

Either move the entire *definition* of `merge` to the top (place it before `mergesort`), or pre-declare `merge` at the top:

```
std::vector <int> merge(std::vector <int> list1, std::vector <int> list2);
```